# ECLIPSE 4.1.0; 4.1.1; Indigo - install/update plugins fail to connect to sites - fail to connect to SVN repo with Subclipse

Tags: eclipse

Need help figuring out why I keep 'getting the following error :

```
permission denied: connect

Unable to read repository at http://update1.aptana.org/rails/1.2.1.23268/content.xml.
```

Permission denied: connect

Basically for all of my installed plug-ins. I was trying to update or install the latest Subclipse plug-in since I can't seem to connect to my repository (even one I knew was working before - and the svn url works elsewhere like with TortoiseSVN).

```
svn: Cannot connect to 'svn+ssh://kosh.nku.edu': There was a problem while connecting to kosh.nku.edu:22
svn: Cannot connect to 'svn+ssh://kosh.nku.edu': There was a problem while connecting to kosh.nku.edu:22
There was a problem while connecting to kosh.nku.edu:22
Permission denied: connect
```

I did switch the interface to SVNkit - which solved the issue before.

I feel like the two issues are connected somehow? I did make sure to turn off the firewall and that didn't change anything.

I am on a Windows 7 laptop - just using my home internet.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Lora

Comment: I think my download of Eclipse 4.1.0 is buggy - so I downloaded Eclipse 4.1.1 and Eclipse Indigo but same problem with 'contacting software sites' occurs. Is there a proper way to  'uninstall' eclipse 4.1.0 - I thought I read Eclipse is just a download and doesn't change any registry keys...

Comment: Normally eclipse is self-contained in what is unzipped.  Sometimes (depending on where it is unzipped) it also creates information in USER_DIR/.eclipse ... but it **will not** touch the registry.

Answer (score 8):

....."adding '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to the **eclipse.ini** under -VMARGS:

```
openFile
-vmargs
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

An alternative is to run Eclipse under a 1.6 jvm by adding

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/javaw.exe
```

above -VMARGS."

*--this worked for me. found solution here: http://www.java.net/node/703177
I am using JDK 7*

Answer (score 1):

I encounter same problem and solved by：

"adding '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to the eclipse.ini under -VMARGS:
After modification，the ini file looks like：

*...
openFile
-vmargs
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
...*

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem with Android SDK and Eclipse 3.7.2. 
Android SDK said: "permission denied: connect".
Eclipse was failed in blue screen.
My laptop is running under Windows Vista and protected by Dr.Web Security Space.

Advises with "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" and "Window --> Preference --> General --> Network Connection --> select Direct" did not help.

Problem was resolved by installing last version of anti-virus without firewall.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Windows 8, I've found many of the programs on the toolbar, etc are not set to run as administrator. Though this didn't seem to make a difference in Windows 7 (perhaps because I was running unzip from the command line in an administrator cmd window), it does now.

I had the problem described in this thread because WinRAR used to unzip the downloaded zip file was not run as administrator so the installation was not properly configured. After removing the installation of eclipse and using the Properties / Shortcut / Advanced to set Run as Administrator on the WinRAR launch icon, then running it and selecting the eclipse download zip and extracting it, I was able to access the Eclipse and Android update sites without any problem. What threw me for a loop was, I was running the Oracle Java 6 JDK 1.6.0.38 so the preferIPv4Stack didn't seem to apply.

I hope this alternative provides insight to others where the IPv4 issue doesn't help.