# Eclipse CVS extssh broken under Windows 7 + Java 7

Tags: eclipse, ssh, cvs, vpn, java-7

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. After installing Java 7 (part of PS3 media server) when I was previously using Java 6, my Eclipse (Indigo Service Release 2, Build id: 20120216-1857) CVS stopped working to the server that's on a VPN. I connect using Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client Version 2.5.2019. The error I get whenever I try to connect to a repository is the following:

```
Could not connect to :extssh:username@example.com:/cvsroot/username/project: CVS communication error:   org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ssh2.CVSSSH2ServerConnection$SSH2IOException: Permission  denied: connect
Permission denied: connect
```

I'm able to work around it by [forcing Eclipse to run under the Java 6 JVM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value%3a_Windows_Example). It's not a firewall issue, because I turned off the Windows firewall, and also Wireshark shows no traffic beyond the DNS lookup.

Both my JREs (Java 6 and Java 7) are 32-bit versions; their paths are respectively

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8142281/1168342) that is to a very similar question, except it involves SVN rather than CVS. The "bug" seems to be that Cisco AnyConnect VPN is not supporting properly IPv6, which is invoked with the newer jre7.

So, adding the following to my `eclipse.ini` is a fix for my situation:

```
openFile
-vmargs
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, the same solution worked for me. I don't think I would've thought of that myself. :-)

Comment: I don't know how you figured that one out, but I agree with @aaamos. BRILLIANT!!! MUCH THANKS!

Comment: @aaamos and DomenicD Glad it worked for you. The 'Permission denied: connect' led me to it, plus persistance with Google. Feel free to vote up the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8142281/1168342) for SVN, as it was the same problem but with a different client.