# Java applet won't run under JRE7, no error displayed in console

Tags: java, windows-7, applet, java-7

Under Windows 7, 64-bit, since upgrading to JRE-7 32-bit, under IE9 32-bit or Chrome, I can't run applets such as [this one](http://profs.etsmtl.ca/mmcguffin/learn/java/01-drawingLines/). Inside the Applet rectangle, I see the message "Error. Click for details"

Clicking on the applet box (blank) leads to a dialogue box:

```
Application Error 
DrawingLines.class
There was an error while executing the application. Click "Details" for more information.
```

Clicking "Details" button opens the Java console, but there are no errors, just

```
Java Plug-in 10.3.0.5
Using JRE version 1.7.0_03-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Blah
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to 
----------------------------------------------------
```

The developer's tools console is blank in both browsers.

If I reload the page, I eventually get a kind of deadlock, where the browser stops responding.

Any idea why no error is showing in the console?

**(edit)**
Because my JREs are 32-bit, the 64-bit version of IE9 doesn't run applets. This makes sense, and the browser reports the message "Your browser is ignoring the APPLET tag" or equivalent. I am using 32-bit JREs because I develop some software based on JMF (which is only compatible with the 32-bit JRE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve the problem:

**Java Control Panel -> Java tab -> View... (and manage Java Runtime versions and settings for Java applications and applets...) -> Find**

Point the search to the Java folder in the Program Files (for a more efficient search). In my case, the control panel found additionally the JDKs (which I also had installed). It already knew about the two JREs I mentioned in the question above.

I accepted the new findings and applets now work in Chrome and IE9.

My *theory* is that something linking browsers to JREs was not right (the browser was launching the JRE, hence I got a console and an error message in the applet rectangle, but it wasn't correct somehow). Scanning for the JREs again fixes the glitch somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Test the Java Version of your browser plugin first: http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp

I have both Java 6 and 7 installed on Windows 64 bit. My browser plugin is still the 6 version. I had not updated the plugin for the 7 version yet.

Comment: That link also has an applet, and so the behavior is the same as above. I tried all the advice on that page, and everything is "enabled". The java version shows in the console window (see above). Btw, do you have 32- or 64-bit jre's?

Comment: I use a 64-bit JDK 7 from Sun/Oracle. Have you tried to unistall your browsers and JVM, remove the config data in the hidden folders of your profile and reinstall the JVM after reinstall them? On Linux, there´s a file the links the "dll" for the browsers, When I updated from 6 to 7, I have to update the link too. After that the (browser + jvm) works nice. Try to remove all JVMs and keep only the 7 version. Maybe, you missing the connection for the Java Plugin dll and the reinstallation could fix it.

Comment: thanks for your help. I just did fresh installs, while trying to solve [this other Java-related problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10270339/1168342). Your comment gave me an idea to try the Control Panel, which seems to have worked (see my answer here).

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I am glad you solved it. See you again later. :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 32 bit

Go to start/all programs/java/configure java
Temporary Internet Files/Settings
Set from none to medium