# Java applet failed to load when visited using HTTPs protocol with Java 7

Tags: java, https, applet

We have a java applet on our website which worked for ages. Then Java 7 came out, people installed it. When people with Java 7 visiting our website using HTTPS, the applet failed to load (ClassNotFoundException). The same site and the same applet, when visit using regular HTTP, it works fine.

People with previous version of Java (1.6.x) can see the applet using either HTTP or HTTPs with no problem.

Anything we can do on our side to resolve this problem for people with Java 7 and like to stay with HTTPS?

Googled and didn't see any relevant result. Any pointer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this thread. Maybe it'll help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290867/java-applet-wont-run-under-jre7-no-error-displayed-in-console

Comment: Search the [bug database](http://bugs.sun.com/) for similar problems.  If you don't see one, raise a bug report.  Report back.

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290867/java-applet-wont-run-under-jre7-no-error-displayed-in-console is not the same issue. That was an application exception on drawing, and this is class loading problem.  Also searched java bug database, saw a similar one for JDK 1.3, but it was fixed in JDK 1.4, almost a decade ago.  Will file a bug with Oracle and see how that goes

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved. Long story short, the reason is that JSSE (Java Secure Socket Extension) implementation in Java 7, by default, has SNI (Server Name Indication) enabled by default, which require the server name set up on the SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) server.

In the case of Apache, we need to do the following:

```
<VirtualHost default:443>

# General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/opt/apache/2.2.21/htdocs"
ServerName your.servername.com:443
```

Previously we have this line commented out and it works for all the browser and all Java Applet, until Java 7 is out.

I had the same discussion on the Java Developer Forum below

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10330444#10330444

Comment: Desmond, it looks like there was a cut and paste or formatting error on your answer. Could you clarify what you did? Supposing your site is https://your.servername.com, you just need to add that ServerName directive with that name to clear up the issue?